# Android: Accessing View object in a Fragment class

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-fragments, view

How do I access the View object created at the onCreateView method of a Fragment class from another method? I need to access the view in order to reference the Gridview control of my layout.

```
public class comments_frag_activity extends Fragment{

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comments_frag, container, false);
}


 //other methods.....
 //other methods .....
 //other methods .....



 public void printTest()
   {
        if(!commentsGallery.isEmpty())
        {
            //I cant access the view object 'android'
            GridView list = (GridView)android.findViewById(R.id.commentinglist);
            CommentsAdapter bA = new CommentsAdapter(ctx, R.layout.comments_frag, commentsGallery);
            list.setAdapter(bA);
        }

}
```

Comment: When your posted code appears other than you'd be proud of in your personal code, reformat it to match. If the code above does not strike you to be ill-formatted; please learn to format your code consistently - for the world's sake.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being ignorant but what's wrong with my format? @ChiefTwoPencils It's very clear and anyone can understand and I made sure that I didn't include any unnecessary methods so that it doesn't confuse anyone :)

Comment: Your indentation should match at least. Much of formatting is stylistic in a personal way, some is not so much. Your edit got you pretty close, and often it's a copy/past issue, but still needs attention. It'd be best to look for resources on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the view to a class variable.

private View view;

......

.....

@Override
 onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
   
    view  = inflater.inflate(your layout)

}

Answer (score 1):

Declare it globally instaed of local variable

Answer (score 1):

```
Try This
public class comments_frag_activity extends Fragment{
private View android; 
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
      android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comments_frag, container, false);
      }


public void printTest()
        {
        if(!commentsGallery.isEmpty())
          {

          GridView list = (GridView)android.findViewById(R.id.commentinglist);
         CommentsAdapter bA = new CommentsAdapter(ctx, R.layout.comments_frag,              commentsGallery);
                list.setAdapter(bA);
            }
         }
```

Comment: `Private` does not compute! Formatting doesn't help either!

Answer (score 1):

Store view's references after onCreateView in onViewCreated:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    localGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.commentinglist);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't won't to store view globally (for some reason), you can always do something like

```
 public void printTest()
   {
        if(!commentsGallery.isEmpty())
        {
            //I cant access the view object 'android'
            GridView list = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.commentinglist);
            CommentsAdapter bA = new CommentsAdapter(ctx, R.layout.comments_frag, commentsGallery);
            list.setAdapter(bA);
        }

}
```

getView() will return the root layout inflated in onCreateView